# How can I append soy template return values as DOM nodes to the document body?

Tags: google-closure-templates

I am currently appending Google Closure Soy templates to the body of my HTML document via

```
var header = app.ui.templates.home.header();
document.body.innerHTML =
  header + app.ui.templates.home.bottom({
      "widgets": widgets,
  });
```

However, I don't believe this is optimal since soy template constructors do not return DOM nodes. Hence, I cannot say call `goog.dom.appendChild(header, someNewElementICreated);`.

Is there a convenient way to convert a soy template (say `header`) into a DOM node? I could just call `goog.dom.$('idOfMyHeader')`, but that would involve a browser reflow operation since a new DOM node is appended to the header after the header has already been displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a convenient way to convert a soy template (say header) into a DOM node?

Closure Templates can be rendered as DOM fragments using the Soy 
JavaScript library function `soy.renderAsFragment`.

**app.js**

```
goog.require('app.ui.templates');
goog.require('soy');

var fragment = soy.renderAsFragment(app.ui.templates.myTemplate, null /*data*/);
goog.dom.appendChild(goog.dom.getElementsByTagNameAndClass('body')[0],
    /** @type {Node} */ (fragment));
```

**templates.soy**

```
{namespace app.ui.templates}

{template .myTemplate}
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
{/template}
```

Since the rendered template in this case is an Element Node, it may be cast to 
a `Node` and appended to the DOM. However, it is more common to use `div` 
elements as placeholders and setting the `innerHTML` attribute.